# Receiving data from multiple connections using select in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm a bit confused about how to keep calling `recv()` when using `select()`. This code isn't complete but it demonstrates the issue. Lets assume we are receiving a decent amount of data from each connection (10,20mb).

Should you keep looping using `recv()` until you get the desired number of bytes after the call to `select()`?

```
while True:
    r,w,e = select.select(r_ready, w_ready, [], timeout)
    for client in r:
        if client == sock:
            acceptConnection(sock)
        else:
            chunks = []
            bytesRead = 0
            while bytesRead < desiredBytes:
                chunk = client.recv(1024)
                bytesRead += len(chunk)
```

Or should you only call recv() once after each select() loop?

```
clientBuffers = {}
while True:
    r,w,e = select.select(r_ready, w_ready, [], timeout)
    for client in r:
        if client == sock:
            acceptConnection(sock)
        else:
            chunk = client.recv(1024)
            clientBuffers[client].append(chunk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should you keep looping using recv() until you get the desired number
>   of bytes after the call to select()?

In general, no; because you have no way of knowing how long that will take.  (e.g. for all you know, the client might not send (or the network might not deliver) the entire sequence of desired bytes until an hour after it sends the first bytes in the sequence; which means that if you stay in a loop calling recv() until you get all of the bytes, then it's possible that all of the other clients will not get any response from your server for a very long time -- clearly not desirable behavior for a multi-client server!)

Instead, just get as many bytes from recv() as you currently can, and if you didn't receive enough bytes to take action yet, then store the received bytes in a buffer somewhere for later and go back to your regular select() call.  select() should be the only place in your event loop that you ever block.  Making all of your sockets non-blocking is highly recommended, in order to guarantee that you won't ever accidentally block inside a recv() call.

Comment: I just want to add this as it may help someone. If your select continues to wait, even after a successful read, it's probably because of buffering on an SSL socket. The pending() method can be used in that case.